# Calculator/Tool to find subgroup of $S_n$ generated by $\langle g_1 \dots g_k \rangle$

Tags: symmetric-groups

does anyone know an online utility tool that computes the subgroup of the symmetric group generated by generators, for example, I want the program to tell me

$$
\langle (13)(24), (13) \rangle = \{ (1), (13)(24), (13), (24) \}
$$

I’ve tried https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/discrete-mathematics/combinatorics/permutations/ and https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/algebra/finite-groups/ but none of the calculators from Wolfram Alpha seem to do what I want

Also, I don’t know if this is off-topic, please delete if these posts are not allowed

Comment: have you tried GAP or Sage ?

Comment: @GreginGre Sage seems to do what I want, 
> sage: PermutationGroup(["(1,3)(2,4)”,”(1,3)”]).list()

Thanks

Comment: But in the first place I didn’t know those programs existed haha

Comment: @GreginGre post an answer!

Comment: The snippet @user651267 provides should be left as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try GAP (specialized in computations for group theory) or SAGE.